# MySQL count how many times foreign key has a given value

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I have one table with states and one table with dates under a given state

```
s_state
---------
#id     name
1       State 1
2       State 2

d_date
--------
#date         #user    state
2017-01-01        1        1
2017-01-02        1        1
2017-01-03        2        1
```

I am trying to get, for a given user, how many times (how many days) he had been with each state. My current query works if the state is used, but my problem is that it doesn't return "count 0" for the states not used. (It would, for user 1, return only "State 1 used 2 times", but I want it to return "State 1 count = 2, State 2 count = 0")

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT s_state.id, COUNT(date)
FROM s_state
LEFT JOIN d_date ON s_state.id = d_date.state
WHERE d_date.user = 1
GROUP BY s_state.id
```

Comment: Do you only have two states or X? I'm assuming you want to join all states to all users regardless if they have an entry?

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to see how many times each states has been used by user X

Comment: Move `d_date.user = 1` to the `ON` clause, as explained in the duplicate question.

Comment: cab you put an IF into your select? like SELECT IF(COUNT(date) > 0, COUNT(date), 0). Not in a position to check, may be count is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    s_state.id AS 'State Id',  
    IFNULL(COUNT(date), 0) AS 'Count'
FROM s_state
LEFT JOIN d_date ON s_state.id = d_date.state AND user = 1
GROUP BY 
    s_state.id, 
    user
```

If you use `user` in `WHERE` clause, it will filter those that do not exist. A `JOIN` will show `NULLs` instead, which you can then convert to 0s